# Java netty rxtx pipeline blocks after writeAndFlush()

Tags: java, netty, rxtx

I'm currently trying to achieve a somewhat stable connection between a micro-controller and a Java-application using netty 4.0.44.Final and rxtx. From time to time the controller asks for a time-stamp, otherwise it is just forwarding sensor data to my application. The application is able to receive as many packages as I want to until i call writeAndFlush() somewhere in the pipeline (i.e. answering a time-request). The pipeline correctly writes data on the outputstream (when writeAndFlush() is called) and from that point onwards my application is never receiving data again and I have no idea why.

```
public class WsnViaRxtxConnector extends AbstractWsnConnector{
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WsnViaRxtxConnector.class);
private String port;
private Provider<MessageDeserializer> deserializerProvider;
private ChannelFuture channelFuture;
public ChannelKeeper keeper;

@Inject
public WsnViaRxtxConnector(Provider<MessageDeserializer> deserializerProvider, ChannelKeeper keeper) {
    this.deserializerProvider = deserializerProvider;
    this.port = Configuration.getConfig().getString("rest.wsn.port");
    this.keeper = keeper;
    System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", this.port);
}

@Override
protected void run() throws Exception
{
    EventLoopGroup group = new OioEventLoopGroup();
    //final EventExecutorGroup group2 = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1500);

    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(RxtxChannel.class)
         .handler(new ChannelInitializer<RxtxChannel>() {
             @Override
             public void initChannel(RxtxChannel ch) throws Exception {
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new DleStxEtxFrameDecoder(), new DleStxEtxFrameEncoder());   
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new IntegrityCheck(),new IntegrityCalculation());
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new AesCcmDecrypter(),new AesCcmEncrypter());
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(deserializerProvider.get(),new MessageSerializer());
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new TimeStampJockel());
             }
         })
          .option(RxtxChannelOption.BAUD_RATE, 19200);
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(new RxtxDeviceAddress(this.port)).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

The handlers are all pretty much standard implementations and seem to work when receiving packages only. The pipeline should first generate an object from the raw data, checkCRC, decrypt, deserialize and then compute some logic (aka generate a time-response).

```
public class TimeStampJockel extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeStampJockel.class);

private EventBus bus;
private ChannelKeeper keeper;

@Inject
public TimeStampJockel(){
    this.bus = GlobalEventBus.getInstance();
    this.keeper = keeper;
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
    LOG.debug("Creating packet from received data");

    RawPacket raw = (RawPacket)msg;

    //EventExecutor ex = ctx.executor();
    //LOG.debug("inexecutor.EventLoop(1):" + ex.inEventLoop());

    //keeper.addChannelHandlerContext(raw.getSource(),ctx);

    ByteBuf buf = raw.getContent();
    LOG.debug("\tBuffer: {}", HelperFunctions.getBufferAsHexString(buf));
    UnsignedLong mac = UnsignedLong.fromLongBits(21);
    while(buf.readerIndex()<buf.writerIndex())
    {
        int type = buf.readShort();
        int length = buf.readShort();
        ByteBuf value = buf.readBytes(length);
        if(PacketType.getEnum(type).equals(PacketType.MAC))
        {
            mac = UnsignedLong.valueOf(value.readLong());
        }
        else
        {
            AbstractPacket packet = PacketFactory.createPacket(PacketType.getEnum(type), raw.getVersion(), raw.getPacketType(), raw.getSource(), raw.getSource(), raw.getDestination(), mac, value);
            if(packet instanceof TimeReqPacket) {
                TimeReqPacket timeReqPacket = (TimeReqPacket) packet;
                Duration d = HelperFunctions.timeSinceYear2000();
                TimeRespPacket newPacket = new TimeRespPacket(Constants.PROTOCOL_VERSION, PacketType.TIME_RESP.getValue(), packet.getGatewayAdr(),UnsignedLong.valueOf(Configuration.getConfig().getLong("rest.wsn.mac", Long.MAX_VALUE)),timeReqPacket.getMac(),timeReqPacket.getMac(),d.getStandardSeconds(),HelperFunctions.getMillisOfDuration(d));

                ctx.write(newPacket);

            } else {
                bus.post(packet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The received sensor data is pushed to a Guava-bus (unless its a time-request) and processed by other components. If the incoming package is a time-request-packet, the previously displayed component should generate a time-stamp-packet and writeAndFlush() is down the pipeline. Any ideas what may cause that issue? I'm pretty much out of ideas - I have been googling the last 10 hours without meaningful results and I have no unchecked resources left. I'm using ubuntu 16.04, thanks in advance.

[EDIT] I tried checking the ChannelFuture, by adding the following code-snippet to the last pipeline handler

```
ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(newPacket);
                f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                        if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                            LOG.error("Server failed to send message", future.cause());
                            future.channel().close();
                        }
                    }
```

[EDIT2] Found my error. It was a netty version conflict. I am working with multiple versions of netty in different projects and was using an older netty version (4.0.13) instead of netty 4.044.final. I have no idea what changed between those versions but I am glad that everything is working properly now.

Comment: Did you check if the ChannelFuture of the write call was successful ? Also where do you flush ? Without calling flush() nothing will be written at the end

Comment: I call the writeAndFlush() exactly where I now call the write - once my time-package is generated (i did a lot of testing and missed re-replacing it).  The bus.post afterwards is some Guava-magic for incoming packages. And I tested the write operation with different receiving devices (Arduino and an iSense-sensor-node) - the time-package always arrived at the serial port. I log what I'm about to sent and i also checked if what i received matches the previously logged bytebuf. It's just that I never receive again.

Comment: Okay I found my error. It was a netty version conflict. apparently version 4.013 lacks some functionality that 4.044 .final provides.